# How to inherit Vue Json

Tags: vue.js

json format

```
{
  "font_color": "red", 
}
```

I received the color with json and I want to apply it to the html immediately.

```
<h2 style="color:{{msg.font_color}}">Test</h2>
```

Comment: When red comes into json, I want to apply it to html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h2 v-bind:style="{ color: `${msg.font_color}` }">Test</h2>
```

Comment: What if you have an image path?

Comment: ```<img src="{{msg.dst_url}}">```Can I do it this way?